# Linux shell extracting substring between matching patterns

Tags: regex, linux, bash

Let's say I have a string `poskek|gfgfd|XLSE|a1768|d234|uijjk` and I want to extract just the `LSE` part.

I only know that there will be `|X` directly before LSE, and `|` directly after the part I am interested in `LSE`.

Comment: Here is the code I am trying: `echo 'poskek|gfgfd|XLSE|a1768|d234|uijjk' | sed 's/.*|X([^|]\+).*/\1/' `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer using `sed` should work, but I always find `sed` to be a bit awkward for regex selection, as it's really intended for replacement (hence why either side of the pattern needs to be flanked with `.*` and the part you actually want needs to be in parentheses). Here's a solution using `grep`:

`grep -Po '\|X\K[^|]+'`

`-P` signals `grep` to use Perl's regex engine which is more advanced

`-o` only prints the matching part of the line

`\|X` match a literal vertical bar and a capital X

`\K` forget what has currently been matched (do not include it in the final output)

`[^|]+` one or more characters other than vertical bars

Comment: I tried your solution it doesn't work. The code I tried is as follows: `echo 'poskek|gfgfd|XLSE|a1768|d234|uijjk' | grep -Po '\|X\K[^|]+'` and I get the following error message: `usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]] [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when] [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered] [--null] [pattern] [file ...] –`

Comment: @JunsuiBantsu It looks like your grep is missing the `-P` option. What do you get when you type `grep --version`?

Comment: I get this: `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`

Comment: You're on FreeBSD/OSX? That explains the problems you've been having. Why does the title of your question say Linux?

Comment: I am a newbie I don't know the difference I thought all non-Windows Shell's are essentially Linux /Unix. So how do I solve my problem on OSX?

Comment: I tried your answer on an Ubuntu machine and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 'poskek|gfgfd|XLSE|a1768|d234|uijjk' | sed -n 's/.*|X\([^|]\+\).*/\1/p'
```

That ought to do the trick.

Explained:

`sed -n` will not print anything unless specified

`s/` - search and replace
`.*|X` - match everything up to and including `|X`
`\([^|]\+\)` - capture multiple (at least one) character that isn't a `|`
`.*` - match the rest of the text (just to "eat it up")
`/\1/p` - Replace all matched text with the first capture, and print

Comment: I tried your answer with the following code it doesn't work. I get back the whole string back. `echo 'poskek|gfgfd|XLSE|a1768|d234|uijjk' | sed 's/.*|X([^|]\+).*/\1/' `

Comment: What you entered isn't verbatim what I wrote... I will update my answer to not print anything for non-matching lines, and you'll have to get the right amount of backslashes into your paste =)

Answer (score 2):

As a pure bash solution, please try:

```
str='poskek|gfgfd|XLSE|a1768|d234|uijjk'
ext=${str#*|X}
ext=${ext%%|*}
echo "$ext"
```

If regex is available, following also works:

```
if [[ $str =~ .*\|X([^|]+) ]]; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

Comment: Or `if [[ $str =~ \|X([^|]+) ]];`

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case, you could do the rather unconventional:

```
awk '$1=="X"{$1="";print}' FS= OFS= RS=\|
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 echo 'poskek|gfgfd|XLSE|a1768|d234|uijjk' | 
   awk -F "|" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) printf "%s", (substr($i,1,1)=="X"?substr($i,2):"")}'
```

where

`-F` is field seperator **=>** '|' 
  `NF` is number of fields

Comment: OP isn't asking for the 3rd group; they're asking for the group that begins with `X`