# How to extract a regex only if surrounded by TWO regex using grep native regex

Tags: regex, bash, grep, substring

In a bash script, I am trying to extract a string marked by two markers one before and one after:

`^<anything><markerbegin>`**string**`<markerend><anything>$`

I can not use Perl type regex (grep -P) due to portability issue across Mac OSX/BSD and Linux.

Pattern that isn't working (derived from [this somewhat different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54543971/linux-shell-extracting-substring-between-matching-patterns)) that I have tried (markers are O and _ ):

```
echo  -n "tagada_OABCD_Tugudu\n" | grep -Po "O\K[^\_]*\_"
ABCD_
```

2 problems: end marker _ displays and not portable due to -P option not always available

Other (working) solution, but with sed:

```
echo  -n  "tagada_Oabcd_Tugudu\n" | sed -n -e 's/.*O\(.*\)_.*/\1/p'
abcd
```

Detailed explanation:

- `-n`: skips non matching lines
- `s`: substitute first string with    second, delimited by /
- `.*O` : matches everything until included    marker O
- `\(.*\)` : delimits a string that can be referenced in the
  substitution part
- `_.*` : marker _ followed by anything
- `p`: prints    the substituted string

Problem: this uses sed that does string substitution which is overkill (requires 2 regex instead of 1), and that I use less often that grep (hence it is not loaded in memory and might execute slower and consume unnecessary resources).

How can I achieve that with just grep ?

Ideally with any generic regex as markers before and after, not just simple one-character markers.

Comment: grep solution would require lookarounds, which needs `-P`.. so your sed solution is the way to go for your given problem..

Comment: It isn't possible without GNU/BSD extensions, or piping grep's output to another program, or storing its output in a variable for further modification using shell's abilities.

Comment: @oguzismail I am looking mostly for OSX / Ubuntu / CentOS compatibility, what GNU/BSD extensions are you refering to? Maybe they are available out of the box which would solve my problem ?

Comment: @Sundeep well at least a solution with -P can do as an intermediate step, if you can offer one  (I am awful at Perl syntax hence my reluctance to -P, but  could accommodate a *simple* Perl regex)

Comment: something like `grep -oP 'str1\K.*?(?=str2)'` where `str1` and `str2` are the two markers

Comment: is there a reason you can't use parameter expansion? `x="tagada_OABCD_Tugudu"` ; y="${x##*O}" ; z="${y%%_*}" ; echo "${z}"` => `ABCD`; or is your real data more complicated than what's been posted in the question?

Comment: @rowboat I need the command to produce the substring for further usage, not only match it.

Comment: @Sundeep  `grep -oP 'str1\K.*?(?=str2)'` is a usable solution except for OSX afaik.

Comment: @markp-fuso frankly never thought of that, thanks for bringing it up. Discovering the full extent of parameters expansion. I like that only builtins are used. I like less the need for two commands with variables, not mentioning the lower readability of parameter expansion compared to regex IMO. Can't this syntax be  shortened in just one command (I read that parameters expansion brackets can enclose multiple levels of brackets) ? I would then accept the lower readability in exchange of a very resource efficient solution.

Comment: `z` could be replaced by `y` => `y="${y%%_*}"`, so one less variable; not sure about combining 2 expansions into a single assignment but if doable it would be less than 'readable'; parameter expansions are faster than `|sed...` which spawns a new OS (sub)process, granted, you won't notice any difference for a single invocation but if/when you get into processing of 10's/100's of K's (millions?) of invocations (eg, loop processing) you'll notice a *BIG* difference in time (ie, param expansion will smoke the `|sed...` sub-process method), also ...

Comment: this Q just prints something to stdout; what if we need to store the result for later use => then we need to store something in a variable; current method becomes `myresult=$(echo ... | sed ...)` => requires spawning 3 sub-processes, which will slow down processing even more, while param expansion would remain the same; yeah, param expansion can be tricky to understand if not used to it, but gets easier with use, and can provide huge performance improvements in certain scenarios; someone not familiar with regex probably doesn't think regex is very 'readable' eh :-)